# Mysql выбор цены и количества

Tags: mysql

Есть некая таблица с содержанием:

```
+------+-------+----------+
| name | price | quantity |
+------+-------+----------+
| alip | 10    | 0        |
+------+-------+----------+
| mime | 200   | 0        |
+------+-------+----------+
| vini | 70    | 1        |
+------+-------+----------+
| simi | 30    | 10       |
+------+-------+----------+
```

Нужно отсортировать в

```
+------+-------+----------+
| name | price | quantity |
+------+-------+----------+
| simi | 30    | 10       |
+------+-------+----------+
| vini | 70    | 1        |
+------+-------+----------+
| alip | 10    | 0        |
+------+-------+----------+
| mime | 200   | 0        |
+------+-------+----------+
```

То есть сначала идет выборка по количеству, если поле меньше одного, то оно полюбому будет идти после поля с количеством большее нуля. Причем потом все товары должны отсортироваться по цене.

Я делаю так:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM `exp` ORDER BY `quantity` ASC) a
ORDER BY `price` ASC
```

Или

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM `exp` WHERE quantity > 0 ORDER BY `price` ASC) a,
(SELECT * FROM `exp` WHERE quantity  < 1 ORDER BY `price` ASC) b
```

Но естественно всё идет не так, как хочется. Не пойму, как сделать правильный запрос.

Пример: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ebf1/8

Comment: Эмъ... сервис временно не доступен на sqlfiddle, поэтому так напишу: а что мешает сразу по двум полям сортировать:

    SELECT * FROM `exp` ORDER BY `quantity` ASC, `price` ASC

UPD: не до конца понял что надо, сейчас исправлю )

Comment: У вас могут быть значения 0.5 в quantity ? Если там целые, то можно смело использовать мой способ, только для цены надо DESC указать. Я че-то на ваши запросы смотрел, а там ASC, хотя по вашему описанию нужен DESC

Comment: Вроде fiddle отвис, [ЭТО](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ebf1/17) разве не то, что надо?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нулевые количества в конце, все по цене.

```
select * from exp
order by quantity<1, price
```

Comment: Насколько понимаю, если количество больше единицы, то тоже надо сортировать по количеству. Просто формулировка какая-то замудренная ))

Comment: @BOPOH, как можно сортировать по двум полям одновременно? ;) сказано же: 

> Причем потом все товары должны отсортироваться по цене.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, сортировать можно и по 10 полям одновременно ) Сначала сортируется по первому, если встречаются одинаковые - тогда по второму полю. Если и тогда встречаются одинаковые (т.е. первые и вторые совпадают), тогда сортировать уже по третьему.

Comment: @BOPOH, нет, это вы уже придумали. вы условия задачи почитайте. четко: те, что меньше 1 в должны идти после тех, у которых количество >1 и все по цене. Вот если там что-то где-то совпадает - это "потом"... и про это ничего не сказано. надо будет будет отсортировано потом, добавлением quantity в конец списка order by.

Comment: честно, я тоже не совсем понял его вопрос) поэтому в своем ответе поставил знак вопроса

Comment: По примерам не сильно понятно, и как-то "сначала идет выборка по количеству", как бы вроде намекает, что по количеству и сортируем, а следующее только порядок сортировки определяет.

Так что здесь только тов. @lampa рассудит ))

Comment: @Ale_x, @BOPOH, Внимательно смотрим табличку

> Нужно отсортировать в

Все понятно и разумно. Товары в наличии сортированы по цене. Товары, которых нет, идут в конце списка, также сортированными по цене. Так товары выводит куча инет-магазов, работающих в т.ч. под заказ (сортировка по цене, возможно, - пользовательская сортировка).

Comment: Такой вопрос, а если есть еще один столбец "статус" со значением 2 (2 = предзаказ), но у них количество тоже по нулям идет. Как тогда выбрать сначала выбрать товары в наличии (quantity > 0, потом товары по предзаказу quantity = 0 && status = 2) и в конце чтобы показывались товары не в наличии с сортировкой по цене?

Comment: @lampa, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/498ac5/6 так?

Comment: @Yura Ivanov Суперски, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Если вам действительно нужен вариант, который указал тов. [@Yura Ivanov](/users/6117/yura-ivanov) (т.е. "с нулевым количеством" - в конце, а "не с нулевым" не обязательно отсортированные по количеству), тогда будет намного лучше использовать немного другой подход:

- создаем дополнительное поле is_absent, которое динамически обновляем (если количество равно 0, то ставим здесь true, обновлять можно, например, тригерами)
- добавляем это поле во все индексы. Если нам будет не нужна указанная в задаче сортировка, тогда можно будет добавить в запрос условие `WHERE is_absent IN (true, false)`

Такой запрос будет обработан намного быстрее, чем использовать `ORDER BY quantity<1`, т.к. в данном случае сработает filesort. Даже добавление индекса по полю quantity не спасет от него.

Кроме того, добавление is_absent очень поможет в ситуации, когда надо убрать отсутствующие товары. Здесь опять же - `WHERE quantity > 0` усложнит запрос (даже при наличии индекса), MySQL не сможет использовать некоторые индексы/оптимизации и т.д.

Т.е. в итоге ваш запрос примет вид:

```
SELECT * FROM exp
ORDER BY is_absent, price
```

Comment: Спасибо, надо будет применить ваш способ.

Comment: @lampa, я только немного не то напечатал:

>> Если нам будет не нужна указанная в задаче сортировка, тогда можно будет добавить в запрос условие

условие с сортировкой не связано. Здесь имелось ввиду немного другое: если вы добавите это поле в уже существующие индексы, тогда надо будет в условие добавить либо `is_absent IN (true, false)`, либо `is_absent = true`, чтобы и остальные ключи индекса срабатывали.

Вообще про индексы (и MySQL) стоит почитать, например, [здесь](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022343.do). Я третью часть еще не читал, только вторую немного (а она для 5.1 всего)

Comment: не согласен. почти со всеми тезисами. очень не удобно.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov чем неудобно? Тем, что у вас запросы будут по индексу отрабатывать? Это будет быстрее, чем filesort. А если там куча здоровых таблиц еще join`ится? copy to tmp table on disk? А оно надо?

Я не говорю, что это идеальное решение, в некоторых случаях стоит сделать по-другому, но в общем случае я не вижу причин отбрасывать это решение.

К тому же данный подход как раз и упоминается в приведенной мною книге, как один из вариантов решения одной из задач.

Comment: @BOPOH, эти задачи далеки от реальности. В образовательных целях может оно и интересно и полезно знать. Не более.  
Если, например, каталог будет грузиться каждую ночь, то дополнительными тригерами/полями/индексами вы затормозите загрузку и можете не успеть в даунтайм.  
Файлсорт у вас будет в любом случае, сортировки меняются кликом по колонке в браузере и на все варианты вы не создадите индексов, а создадите - см. выше.  
Кроме всего прочего вы забываете про кэширование запросов. Это основная причина не выдумывать новых сущностей без необходимости.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, в реальности я работаю с записями порядка 1М+. Если индекс правильный, то хуже он не сделает, наоборот выигрыш будет - не несколько часов ждать пока какая-то операция завершится, а всего несколько секунд (максимум - минут). Но "правильный" индекс или нет ясно только на готовой системе (по таблице, конечно, понять будет трудно), поэтому и "в некоторых случаях стоит сделать по другому"

В каталоге будет явно меньше миллиона записей (там 10К хоть наберется-то?), а значит выгоды от индекса будет гораздо больше, чем трудностей. Ваш же пример при join`е не улучшить.

Comment: @BOPOH, я не писал, что индексы вовсе не нужны. Вы просто предложили добавить еще одно поле (вычислимое!) во все индексы - это из разряда бреда. Такие индексы почти наверное использоваться не будут, потому что составные и большие. А вот при вставке/апдейте пересчитываться будут постоянно.  
Вы работаете с миллионом записей (сразу) на select'ы. В интернет магазинах select'ы выполняться гораздо реже чем update или insert (загрузка 100к товаров ежедневно - нормальная практика: обновление цен и количеств, новые позиции). А выполненные select'ы попадают сразу в кэш и больше базу не дергают.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, возможно стоило написать "во все необходимые индексы".

Тот же пример здесь: а если данные в разных таблицах и дана выборка? А если кол-во в таблице (id, quantity) находится? Куда индекс добавлять?

Триггеры - тоже только вариант, я же не знаю какая работа планируется. Когда загружаешь данные - разве нельзя сразу же указывать есть товар или нет?

В кэш тоже не все попадет. Да и без кэша на простых запросах при малом кол-ве данных ваш вариант скорее всего не будет заметно тормозить.

Но без конкретного примера/базы трудно что либо говорить.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select name, price, quantity
FROM exp
ORDER BY quantity DESC, price
```

так ?

Comment: @Ale_x, Какбы @BOPOH уже об этом рассказал... Не смущает?

Comment: @deonis, Как бы @BOPOH ответил SELECT * FROM `exp` ORDER BY `quantity` ASC, `price` ASC

Comment: @Deonis, если бы я отвечал - ответ был бы в ответах, я прокомментировал ))

@Ale_x, Первое, да - не прочитал в каком порядке надо сортировать. Второе - опять да, перепутал, что в каком порядке надо сортировать. Но третье - уже то, что надо )